# integral of $ \int (x^3+1)^{1/3} / x^2 dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

What do you think about 
$$ \int \frac {(x^3+1)^{1/3}}{x^2}\,  dx $$

how do you compute this ? Is it possible to use the Euler substitution?

In fact, I don't know if the integral on my sheet is $$ \int \frac {(x^3+1)^{1/3}}  {x^2} \, dx $$
or 
$$ \int \frac{x^2 + 1}{x \sqrt {x^4 - x^2 + 1} } \frac {(x^3+1)^{1/3}}  {x^2}  \,dx $$

would the second expression make more sense? I thought that the second one is a little bit over complicated.

Comment: This integral leads to a hypergeomtric function

Comment: What do you mean. I dont know this expression

Comment: actually I have done a sumary of some usefull integration exercices, and because of the fact I have soon exams, I'm trying to do some of them again. And at the bottom of it is written (exactly like this ) $$ \int \frac{x^2 + 1}{x \sqrt {x^4 - x^2 + 1} } \frac {(x^3+1)^{1/3}}  {x^2}  dx $$ so I don't know if it is a mistake, or if it is two integrals. Because $$ \int \frac{x^2 + 1}{x \sqrt {x^4 - x^2 + 1} } $$  can be quiet easily done

Comment: Hi, you should not edit an answer so essentially. I suggest, to simply post your improvements as a new answer (you can answer your own post, you don't get reputation for accepting your own answer, but you can get rep for the votes). Your edit should be rejected, but you can post it as an answer. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1024464) you can get the link to the review.

Comment: okay I understand. I just wanted him to have the rewards and not myself :) Thank you

Comment: Incidentally  $$\int \frac{(x^3+1)^{1/3}}{x^2} \, dx-\int \frac{1}{x^2 \left(x^3+1\right)^{2/3}} \, dx=\int \frac{x}{\left(x^3+1\right)^{2/3}} \, dx=-\frac{(x^3+1)^{1/3}}{x}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hint :  Divide numerator & denominator by $x$ & write the integrand 
>   as $I= \int\frac {(1+\frac1 {x^3})^{1/3}}x dx $

The whole calculus :
\begin{align}
 I  =& \int \frac{(x^3 +1)^{1/3} }{x^2} dx \\
    =& \int \frac{(1+ x^{-3})^{1/3} }{x} dx
\end{align}

---

let $y= x^{-3} \implies dy = \frac{-1}{3} x^{-4} dx $ 
$$ I = \frac{-1}{3} \int \frac {(1+y)^{1/3}}ydy  $$

---

let $ z^3 = 1+y \implies  dz =3z^2dy$

\begin{align}
 I &= \int \frac {z^3}{1-z^3}dz \\
   &= \int \frac{z^3 + 1 - 1}{1-z^3}dz \\
   &= \int \frac{z^3 - 1}{1-z^3}dz + \int \frac{ 1 }{1-z^3}dz \\
   &= - \int  dz + \int \frac{ 1 }{1-z^3}dz \\
however \\
   \int  \frac{ 1 }{z^3-1}dz  &= \int \frac{1}{  (z-1)(z^2+z+1) } dz \\ 
   &= \frac{1}{3} \int \frac{1}{z-1} dz - \frac{1}{3} \int \frac{z+2}{z^2 + z + 1} dz  \\ 
   &=\frac{1}{3} \int \frac{1}{z-1} dz - \frac{1}{6} \int \frac{2z+1}{z^2 + z + 1} dz  - \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{z^2 + z + 1} dz \\
   &=\frac{1}{3} \int \frac{1}{z-1} dz - \frac{1}{6} \int \frac{2z+1}{z^2 + z + 1} dz  - \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{ (z+ \frac{1}{2})^2 + (\frac{\sqrt 3}{2})^2 } dz \\
   &=\frac{1}{3} \ln( z-1 ) - \frac{1}{6} \ln(z^2 + z + 1) - \frac{1}{\sqrt 3} \arctan ( \frac{2z + 1}{ \sqrt 3} ) + cst \\
so \\
I &= -z + \frac{1}{3} \ln( z-1 ) - \frac{1}{6} \ln(z^2 + z + 1) - \frac{1}{\sqrt 3} \arctan ( \frac{2z + 1}{ \sqrt 3} ) + cst \\
i.e. \\
I &= -\sqrt[3]{1 + x^{-3} } + \frac{1}{3} \ln( \sqrt[3]{1 + x^{-3} } -1 ) - \frac{1}{6} \ln(\sqrt[3]{1 + x^{-3} } ^2 + \sqrt[3]{1 + x^{-3} } + 1) \\ &- \frac{1}{\sqrt 3} \arctan ( \frac{2\sqrt[3]{1 + x^{-3} } + 1}{ \sqrt 3} ) + cst \\
\end{align}

> $$ \int\frac {(1+\frac1 {x^3})^{1/3}}x dx = -\sqrt[3]{1 + x^{-3} } +
>  \frac{1}{3} \ln( \sqrt[3]{1 + x^{-3} } -1 )  \\ - \frac{1}{6}
>  \ln(\sqrt[3]{1 + x^{-3} } ^2 + \sqrt[3]{1 + x^{-3} } + 1) -
>  \frac{1}{\sqrt 3} \arctan ( \frac{2\sqrt[3]{1 + x^{-3} } + 1}{ \sqrt
>  3} ) + cst $$

Comment: Isn't this the wrong way around "$y= x^{-3} \implies dy = \frac{-1}{3} x^{-4} dx
$"

Comment: @JamesArathoon what do you mean

Comment: start with $x=y^{-1/3}$ and differentiate that

Comment: Wait what? First, the idea of Lord KK was great so I just wanted to improve the answer in order to have a whole answer. An administrator told me (check the comments section) to not do that. I just wanted to keep a track of the entire work.  So i ve written my own answer which is basically the same one but with all of the calculus. I m sorry if there is any mistake, i dont understand where, i ve checked it again and I dont understand your point... Really sorry. If you want to edit it, go freely.

Comment: Sorry my mistake your not out by a factor of 3. I will delete my comment above leaving the recommendation here to explicitly reference @Lord KK 's contribution for the method you have used in your answer.

Comment: I m really sorry if I created a fuss, my objective has never been to steal (in which way would really not be subtle) someone else s idea. I just really wanted to finish the job

Comment: Ok I see so I slightly misunderstood the situation. Anyway it's sorted now so don't worry about it

Answer (score 4):

Hint :  Divide numerator & denominator by $x$ & write the integrand  as $I= \int\frac {(1+\frac1 {x^3})^{1/3}}x dx $

Now, write $y= (1/x)^3 \implies  I = (-1/3)\int \frac {(1+y)^{1/3}}ydy $

Now, write $1+y =z^3 \implies dy=3z^2dz \implies  I = \int \frac {z^3}{1-z^3}dz$

From here you can use partial fraction to calculate the final integral.

Comment: cool stuff.....